# Magento error after moving website to another server

Tags: magento

I just transferred my website to another server by using this guide: http://www.atwix.com/magento/moving-magento-to-another-server/

but when i access the it gives me this error. What does it means? what do i need to do to make it work?

```
Warning: include(Zend/Log.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/site/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'Zend/Log.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/site/app/code/local:/var/www/site/app/code/community:/var/www/site/app/code/core:/var/www/site/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/site/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93

Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Log' not found in /var/www/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 247
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i can see, it looks like the file in question can't be found at all. What to do is check the directory `/www/work/newshop/lib/Zend` and make sure the log file is within there. If not, double check your previous server and see if it's there as well. It's possible for you to have just missed it.

If it IS there, make sure permissions are set accordingly. eg; the log.php file should have it's permissions set to 644.  (Read and Write for owner, Read for group and read for public)

Answer (score 0):

did you remove the cache folder from Magento After moved your installation?
And wich PHP Version ist installed on the new Server?
Magento have already problem with php5.4 and php5.5 (reference: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62639)